# Date conversion from numbers to words in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, date-conversion

I wrote a program in python(I'm a beginner still) that converts a date from numbers to words using dictionaries. The program is like this:

```
dictionary_1 = { 1:'first', 2:'second'...}
dictionary_2 = { 1:'January', 2:'February',...}
```

and three other more for tens, hundreds, thousands;

- 2 functions, one for years <1000, the other for years >1000;
- an algorithm that verifies if it's a valid date.

In main I have:

```
a_random_date = raw_input("Enter a date: ")
```

(I've chosen raw_input for special chars. between numbers such as: 21/11/2014 or 21-11-2014 or 21.11.2014, only these three) and after verifying if it's a valid date I do not know nor did I find how to call upon the dictionaries to convert the date into words, when I run the program I want at the output for example if I typed 1/1/2015: first/January/two thousand fifteen. 
And I would like to apply the program to a text document to seek the dates and convert them from numbers to words if it is possible.
Thank you!

Comment: If you're doing this for learning purposes, that's fine, but you should be aware that there is a standard library function for this:  [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spell out each word of a date in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087403/spell-out-each-word-of-a-date-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split that date in list and then check if there is that date in dictionary like this:

```
import re

dictionary_1 = { 1:'first', 2:'second'}
dictionary_2 = { 1:'January', 2:'February'}
dictionary_3 = { 1996:'asd', 1995:'asd1'}

input1 = raw_input("Enter date:")
lista = re.split(r'[.\/-]', input1)
print "lista: ", lista
day = lista[0]
month = lista[1]
year = lista[2]
everything_ok = False
if dictionary_1.get(int(day)) != None:
   day_print = dictionary_1.get(int(day))
   everything_ok = True
else:
   print "There is no such day"
if dictionary_2.get(int(month)) != None:
   month_print = dictionary_2.get(int(month))
   everything_ok = True
else:
   print "There is no such month"
   everything_ok = False
if dictionary_3.get(int(year)) != None:
   year_print = dictionary_3.get(int(year))
   everything_ok = True
else:
   print "There is no such year"
   everything_ok = False
if everything_ok == True:
   print "Date: ", day_print, "/", month_print, "/", year_print #or whatever format
else:
   pass
```

This is the output:

```
Enter date:1/2/1996
Date:  first / February / asd
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: @nickyd No problem! Btw. please mark answer as correct by clicking "check" button near correct answer ;)

Comment: When I implemented this part I got an error message:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nick/data.py", line 142, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/nickdata.py", line 110, in main
    month = list[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I enter a date with raw_input, it verifies if it is a valid date and after i added the code you suggested I got the above error, what should I do?

Comment: I edited my answer, now it works. Sorry for this, I haven't actually checked my code since I was in hurry... Sorry again. @nickyd

Comment: Thanks, nothing to apologize for, I was wondering: is there a way to display the special character the user inputs? For example: enter date 31.13.2014 => thirty first. December. two thousand fourteen or 31/12/2014 => split by/ or 31-12-2014 => split by - ....any character the user inputs to be displayed at the output

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you will need the re module.  Learn to write a regular expression that can search strings of a particular format.  Here's some code example:

```
with open("mydocument.txt") as f:
    contents = f.read()

fi = re.finditer(r"\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}", contents)
```

This will find all strings that are made up of 1 or 2 digits followed by a hyphen, followed by another 1 or 2 digits followed by a hyphen, followed by 4 digits.  Then, you feed each string into `datetime.strptime`; it will parse your "date" string and decide if it is valid according to your specified format.

Have fun!