# Spell out each word of a date in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, date, python-datetime

In Python 3, I would like to change 2018-01-01 to "January first, two thousand and eighteen".  I looked at the format guide in [the Python datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)
but I did not see a format for spelling out the day of the month or for spelling out the year.  Is there a well-known module that can do this (I am new to Python)?

Comment: You might find the [inflect](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) package useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the inflect module, as commented by [@ Lakshay Garg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087403/spell-out-each-word-of-a-date-in-python-3#comment91125190_52087403) you can do:

```
import datetime as dt, inflect

p = inflect.engine()

def date_in_words(x):
     a = dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d')
     return (a.strftime('%B ')+p.number_to_words(p.ordinal(int(a.day)))+', ' + 
     p.number_to_words(int(a.year)))

date_in_words('2018-03-14')
Out[259]: 'March fourteenth, two thousand and eighteen'
```